# Ideas on limit the text on textfield?

Tags: javascript, html

for example, I want the textfield input number only. my idea is when the user typing, it will call a javascript to check whether it is valid, if it is not valid, I delete the text which is just entered. But I think it is very complex to do so. Is there any simple way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery Masking could be a good choice: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

Put a validation on submit.

Answer (score 0):

The script to do this is here.  It's a pretty common requirement.

http://javascript.internet.com/forms/validate-numeric-only.html

Answer (score 0):

I think, like o.k.w said, jQuery Masking would be a good choice because of 2 things:

1. jQuery is solid and fast
2. Masking is more user friendly than just deleting user input on the fly without any notification. Masking gives them a graphical reference of what type of input is expected and what the input might look like.